# Control draft saving in Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app, mobileme, macos

Is it at all possible to change the time for saving drafts in Apple Mail? I use MobileMe and whenever I send an email, the draft doesn't get deleted automatically. I don't want to switch off saving of drafts, but would like to increase the time between saves. Since I don't need to save drafts for short emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go into Preferences, Accounts, select your account, then select the "Mailbox Behaviors" tab, there's an option to disable saving drafts on the server. I know you said you didn't want to disable saving of drafts, but this option will still save the draft on your computer, yet it won't mess up Mobile Me.

Comment: Lacking any better solutions this would be valid. I use different devices and even my browser, so when I do have important emails having them on the server in draft is useful. Definitely an option however, and a valid one, but not ideal for me yet.