# Mail 7.2 issues with drafts

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

When I type a reply email multiple copies of this email get saved in drafts.

I've read over the posts tagged `mail.app` and I thought I hit the jackpot with [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6335/10733) answer by @Kyle, but when I navigate to Accounts>Mailbox Behaviours there is no option for disabling saving drafts on the server, 
or am I missing something?
[image]
I am running Mail 7.2 on an MBP with OS X Mavericks 10.9.2

**When I type a reply email multiple copies of this email get saved in drafts**, then these drafts all appear when I have View>Organize by Conversation ticked. Our company uses gmail as our mail service. This does not happen when I use my own gmail account.

This is really annoying as when I am writing a long email, there can be an additional 20 "emails" in the email trail.

I get the same behaviour whether I am running IMAP or POP.

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: please explain using your own gmail account? is it on same computer, is it also in the work place or at home,

Comment: @Buscar웃 when I say my own gmail account I mean my personal gmail account.  I have set it up on the same computer that has the issue (running 10.9.2), and also on a different MBP running 10.7.5.  This happens both at work and at home.  If I have not made anything clear please let me know I can provide more screenshots etc. Also I can jump on chat.

Comment: Well your "Mailbox behavior" is mess up? it is missing a option "Draft"? so I wanted to know if that is same on both accounts, and if it is you need to fix your mail.app installation.

Comment: Let me check, one tick, I get what you are saying.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I think I found the issue, the drafts configuration in "Mailbox behaviours" only appears for IMAP accounts, it does not appear for POP accounts, as I have been trying to resolve this I set up a POP account rather than an IMAP.

Comment: If the problem is solved (sort of) make that findings as an answer so we can move on.

Comment: Yes, sir,@Buscar웃 sir, will do. Just busy with work right now, I will write up the answer, even have the screenshots ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue was the fact that I had set up the account as a POP account in apple mail.

When IMAP is selected the following screen appears:
[image]
and as can be seen the first item is the one I was looking for.

Drafts : Store draft messages on the server.

**When the option above is not ticked the issue stops.**